# FCM production and dev notification getting from console but not from dot net server

Tags: ios, asp.net, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am facing issue in FCM notification, I have created p12 file of development and production and uploaded to FCM console and I am getting both notification on my device. I gave same certificates to back end side(dot net developer) however I am getting only development notification from backend side but not getting production notification. So is there any issue at app side? or it is backend issue? there is no issue of certificate at back end.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you explained it looks the issue is totally from backend side.
please go through the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingwithAPNs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH11-SW1)

> **APNs Connections**
>
> The first step in sending a remote notification is to establish a
>   connection with the appropriate APNs server:
>
> **Development server:** api.development.push.apple.com:443
>
> **Production server:** api.push.apple.com:443

I think ; The Backend guys should use the production server for sending the payload by which you will get notification in production. Currently they had use development server.

Comment: @Amit Atale Answer is helpful ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will check with backend guy.